# Regular language using pumping lemma

Tags: regular-languages

a^2n b^(2n+1) is a regular language. 
I am not able to decompose it in xyz so that I can pump any power of y as per pumping lemma. Please help me out.

Comment: The langauge is not regular.

Comment: Thanks David.I was attempting MCQ's and came across this question.May be the answer given is wrong. Thanks

Comment: Our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/599/reference-answers-to-frequently-asked-questions) may help you sort out misunderstandings.

Answer (score 2):

You probably misunderstood the question. For starters, the pumping lemma can't be used to prove that a language is regular, it can only be used to prove that a language *isn't* regular. The Wikipedia page for the [pumping lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages#Converse_of_lemma_not_true) gives a counterexample.

Secondly, as already pointed out by @DavidRicherby, this particular language is *not* regular, and as it turns out, you *can* use the Pumping Lemma to prove *this* statement.

Roughly speaking, the proof goes as follows:

Assume for the sake of contradiction that the language is regular, and thus, the Pumping Lemma holds. The "y" can take one of three forms:

1. y contains all "a"s
2. y contains all "b"s
3. y is of the form $a^ib^j$ for some $i,j > 0$.

Now, can you see how to derive the contradiction?

Comment: Thanks Dennis.I did it in the same way but the answer was that it is a regular language.So i posted it here because the answer provided by this forum can not be wrong.

Comment: @DennisMeng: Thanks, have fun! Your time is much better spent on questions that have not been answered multiple times already.

Comment: True. That last bit will probably just come down to me getting a better idea of what's been repeated over and over here; I'll spend more time just observing to get an idea of what those are.

Comment: @DennisMeng Basically, if it's an exercise from undergrad TCS courses, we've probably got it covered. (We don't have as much non-theory stuff around, unfortunately.) That should not prevent you from answering *good* questions; these often vary enough (because the included attempts differ) to leave them open.